# Hook into laravel 4 artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there a way to hook into an artisan command easily?  What I'm looking to accomplish is have a piece of code executed everytime the `php artisan migrate` command is executed.

Comment: You may be able to extend the [`MigrationServiceProvider`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/33bfc4eb6fe9fca3ea9c5c0fb54acfbdb8f432bb/MigrationServiceProvider.php) or the [`MigrateCommand`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/33bfc4eb6fe9fca3ea9c5c0fb54acfbdb8f432bb/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php) it calls.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a listener some place in your code (even at the top of app/start/artisan.php) to listen for the 'artisan.start' event.

```
Event::listen('artisan.start', function($app)
{
    // $app is instance of Illuminate\Console\Application
    // since the $app hasn't figured the command yet you'll
    // have to do it yourself to check if it's the migrate command
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this (you may put it in the `filters.php` file):

```
Event::listen('artisan.start', function($app) {
    if( isset($_SERVER['argv'][1]) && $_SERVER['argv'][1] == 'migrate' ) {
        // do something because it's migrate command
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Schema Builder facade and override the build function like so:

```
protected function build(Blueprint $blueprint)
{
      your_function();
      Parent::build($blueprint);
}
```

However, your function won't be called when using the --pretend option for the migrate. I don't know of any built-in ways to hook into the migration without extending either the Schema Builder or Migrator classes.